# How to use c static library in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, static-libraries

I have library header files and static library compiled with XCode SDK from C sources. How to use it in my iOS app? I believe i have to add .a file in the project settings (link section) and header files in source files settings. What about using .mm files instead of .m? How to wrap C API to Objective-c correctly?

Comment: what have you tried? yes, you need to link the object file and you also need to include the header files. you shouldn't have any .mm or .m files as it's already a compiled binary. you should only have .a and the header files.

Comment: .m file stands for message file in objective-c and it's not compiled file.

Comment: You shouldn't have any `.m` or `.mm` files with a compiled C static library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.mm`.  This is only for Objective-C++ files.

All you need to do is include the `.a` and `.h` files in your project (I think you can just drag and drop) and then `#import` the `.h` files in the files you want to use the library in.

In older versions of Xcode you had to manually make sure the `.a` was being linked, but I'm quite positive that this is handled automatically now when you drop the library into the project.

If drag&dropping isn't working, you can right click in your projects list of files and click "Add files", which will open a finder window.  From here, navigate to the `.a` and `.h` files, select them all, and include them.

Comment: Update: XCode 12 does not auto add it to the Link with Binaries step by dragging lib file into project, so still have to do that as well

Answer (score 2):

When using C in objective-C, there is no need to really do anything except use the C code. This is because Obj-c is a superset of C, which basically means that any c code you want to use, you can use it with obj-c. .mm is for objective-c++, which is where you will have the ability to use all c++ code.

When using the library, just put the .a file within your project settings, and then in your .m, or .h file, just `#import <.hfiles>` and that should work...

Comment: so i should use .mm files only is if i link with .a files created using c++ and c++ header files?

Comment: Yes, as my answer states, `.mm` is for Objective-C++.