# Cordova plugin to communication with C library

Tags: objective-c, c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

does anyone knows of a cordova plugin that can communicate with a C library?

In my project I need to pass some data through a C library. From what I understand I need to go through javascript -> objective-c -> C in order to do what I want. Little issue, I don't know Objective C, or Swift.

If anyone's heard of that please let me know.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cordova plugin that communicate with a c library is the Cordova framework itself!

When you call from a Cordova plugin the `exec` function, Cordova will search for a mapped action in the native layer to execute.

When you are in the iOS native layer you can use functions from a C library: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752352/make-static-library-for-ios-with-existing-c-code-in-xcode), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970500/how-to-use-c-static-library-in-ios-app), [and also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778087/how-to-build-a-c-library-for-ios-by-xcode-6) to know how include a C library in a Xcode project (search here for more interesting questions).

By the way, a very common task among iOS developers is to include and use the OpenSSL library: this library is written in C.

See the [plugin development documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#the-javascript-interface) and the [iOS plugin platform documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins) for more information.

Comment: thank you very much for you reply. I will look at the links you gave. As I said I'm fairly new to Objective-C and all.

Comment: Is it possible to implement a steam based communication with a C library? I need to implement a pipe communication between library and the front end?.